# Gradle Android Maven Plugin doesn't create the pom file automatically

Tags: java, android, gradle, maven-plugin, pom.xml

I would like to know how to create a pom file with "Gradle Android Maven Plugin".

I followed the steps on http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html (chapter "Convention Methods"). I also created the directory "buildDir" and get no errors. The App was build successfully but nevertheless the pom file doesn't exist. I am using Android Studio IDE.

Is it possible that the newpom.xml file exists on runtime only and does not exist in my project folder buildDir after runtime? Maybe I am looking for something which can't be found.

My app/build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
apply plugin: 'maven'
task writeNewPom << {
    pom {
        project {
            inceptionYear '2008'
            licenses {
                license {
                    name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                    url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    distribution 'repo'
                }
            }
        }
    }.writeTo("$buildDir/newpom.xml")
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile files('libs/retrofit-1.5.1.jar')
}
```

Can someone tell me if I missed something? :)

Best Regards,
Philip

Answer (score 0):

No need to create buildDir manually, it has default value and refer to /build folder that place in same folder as build.gradle file.

Did you run follow command?

```
gradle writeNewPom
```

after run it I got newpom.xml file in projectroot/build folder, BUT it contains no dependencies however I have dependencies in build.gradle file.

Comment: I've tried your solution, but i got `Gradle version 1.10 is required. Current version is 2.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl`. How to solve this?